# Cannot serialize Kotlin type with Moshi AND R8

Tags: android

i have this strange problem. When using minify/obfuscation with R8 i have the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type <omitted>auth.model.ErrorResponse. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.
```

With no minify/obfuscation everything it's ok. I'm using

```
     val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
                .add(BigDecimalAdapter)
                .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                .build()
```

as readme from moshi, stated. Also in gradle i'm using

```
 implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.3")
```

and added rules

```
-keep class com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
-keep class <omitted>auth.model.ErrorResponse
```

but still have the same exception. what am i missing ?

Thanks

**updated**

here's my BigDecimalAdapter

```
object BigDecimalAdapter {
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(string: String) = BigDecimal(string)

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: BigDecimal) = value.toString()
}
```

Comment: Can you please include your `BigDecimalAdapter` implementation?

Comment: question updated with bigdecimaladapter, thanks!

Comment: is `BigDecimal` your custom class or the one from `math` library? I am having trouble seeing where the `auth.model.ErrorResponse` class comes from, and how it ties in to your Moshi classes. For now, check my potential answer.

Comment: i'll give it a go and i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

try adding to your proguard:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson <methods>;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson <methods>;
}
```